# S3 notification configuration is ambiguously defined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use Terraform to connect two AWS lambda functions to an S3 event.

My configuration looks like this:

```hcl
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "collection_write" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.fruit.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.apple.arn
    events              = [ "s3:ObjectCreated:*" ]
    filter_prefix       = "foo/"
  }

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.banana.arn
    events              = [ "s3:ObjectCreated:*" ]
    filter_prefix       = "foo/"
  }
}
```

But AWS / Terraform doesn't like this:

```
Error: Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.
    status code: 400
```

How should I write this in Terraform?

Answer (score 4):

your terraform is not wrong it is just that s3 is limited to a single event notification. It is better to have the s3 event sent to an SNS topic which then triggers the lambdas to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: This is frustrating. It feels like this limitation was put there to encourage you to use more AWS services!

Answer (score -1):

You can also achieve triggering multiple Lambda functions via AWS SQS. AWS SQS is powerful and easy to use Messaging queue for such use cases.